# Yii выпадающее меню

Tags: yii

Вот есть такое меню:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'items'=>array
            (
                array('label'=>'Регистрация', 'url'=>array('/user/registration'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Вход', 'url'=>array('/user/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Выход ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Управление', 'url'=>array('/'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name=="admin"),
                array('label'=>'Профиль', 'url'=>array('/user/profile'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            ),
            )); ?>
```

При наведении на пункт УПРАВЛЕНИЕ должно выпадать меню.
Как это реализовать с помощью CSS, знаю, но как в вышеуказанном коде показать те подпункты, что должны выпасть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждого пункта есть `items` работающий аналогично

Comment: array('label'=>'Управление', 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->name=="admin", 'items'=>array(
                                array('label'=>'Категории'),
                                array('label'=>'Приложения'),
                                array('label'=>'Пользователи'),
                                array('label'=>'Заявки на добавление'),
                                ),),

Так? чтото я все ж не так сделала. меню не выпадает

Comment: спасибо. разобралась=)

Answer (score 2):

страндартный CMenu вложенностей не сделает, я для етого использовал расширение  CssMenu. Если не найдешь где скачать - напиши куда скинуть

а вот и [ссылочка](https://github.com/mrkmg/yii-ext-cssmenu)

Comment: По подсказке VasyOk, я получила меню вида:

<ul>
<li>
</li>
...
<li>
  <ul>
  <li>
  </li>
   </ul> 
</li>
...
</ul>

Используя display:none и display:block, я сделала выпадающее меню. Но CssMenu возьму на заметку=) Спасибо